# Autohotkey only replace text in URL field

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to set up AHK only when I'm typing it in to the URL portion of a browser. That way I can continue to use my keyword other places.

Is this possible? I've been trying to mess around some with `ifWinActive("ahk_exe chrome.exe") which almost works, however when I try to type it not in the URL it simply deletes the text (and also will still make the replacement even if I'm typing in to a separate text box in the browser, not the URL box.)

Comment: You could  maybe do a conditional winactive case using the coords and bounds on the address bar?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.  Once the command is limited to chrome, you have to do a conditional test to see if you are in the address bar or not. If not, simply "return" without doing anything.

For chrome, window spy however does not indicate the "focused Control" that you could use with "ControlGet" and its related commands:

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlGet.htm

Oh well, so in your hotkey result, you may have to first do a quick copy all from your current caret position to clipboard and then see if the clipboard result is text only and starts with "http" and has a "://" and at least one "." and is otherwise a fully formed url address, and if so, then go ahead and run your hotkey result because now you can be pretty sure you actually are in the address bar.

Klugey, but certainly possible.